# WebStorm HTML and CSS Formatting like Sublime

Tags: sublimetext2, webstorm

In sublime I can format blocks of code with

```
ctrl + {
```

Which goes right and this takes the highlighted code left

```
ctrl + }
```

I've not been able to do that with WebStorm and it's something I keep trying to do with that shortcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebStorm has different shortcut for indenting (Tab) and un-indenting (Shift-Tab). You can modify the shortcuts in Preferences | Keymap.

Comment: Thank you very much. :) Shift tab it is than. :)